# Select query doesnt bring back values even though criteria is met VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm coding a query that finds the shift if the date is correct and the username of the shift employee is selected. Usually there would be 7 labels for each day of the week but I narrowed it down for the sake of getting this part of the code to work, I've been stuck for an hour or so. Here is my code:

```
Dim strQuery as String = "SELECT [Time] FROM [ShiftDetails]" +
" WHERE ([Day] = '" & Label2.Text & "' & [Username] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')  " + 
"Or  ([Day] = '" & Label3.Text & "' & [Username] = '" & cboUser.Text & "')"

myCommand = New OleDbCommand(strQuery, myConnection)
```

Or here it is with colored syntax
http://prntscr.com/5oo6wz

When I did breakpoints I saw that label is the actual date and text is the username so theres nothing wrong with the label/textbox I dont think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use & for join conditions, use AND

```
myCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [Time] FROM [ShiftDetails] WHERE ([Day] = '" & Label2.Text & "' AND [Username] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')  Or  ([Day] = '" & Label3.Text & "' AND [Username] = '" & cboUser.Text & "')", myConnection)
```

Also I hope this is your test query and not the real one as it is prone to sql injection.

Comment: This fixed the problem, thankyou, will give you the upvote when I'm allowed to

Comment: by any chance would you know how to stop duplicate results appearing in a combobox when I use the reader command? This is a real query, its a simple school project which is not planned for public use

Comment: use distinct keyword in your sql query that is bringing results for your reader. see updated answer

Comment: thankyou - I used distinct in a different query populating usernames to a combobox, you have been a great help and saved me alot of time